Disable Microsoft Teams event notifications from a specific user
I keep getting notifications in my Activity feed from a specific person scheduling lots of things in advance, for tons of people, sometimes upwards of 50 per day. It's cluttering up my feed with things like [Some Body] added an event.
This is the only person I want to block, and I probably don't want to block, say, Chat messages from them, just the event notifications. But under Settings-Notifications and activity-Meetings or -Calendar, I see nothing I can use to block for someone specific, only to block all notifications.

Not in Teams. Like you've found, you can disable notifications for calendar invite activity, but it applies to your whole calendar
